# Why does SSIS truncates a column at 32768 chars

Tags: sql-server, ssis

So I have this Data Flow in SSIS, it reads data From flat file, then converts text columns to Unicode (DT_NTEXT) and uploads it to an SQL Server table.
One of the columns can have more than 200k chars in a single value.
When I run the package SSIS quietly truncates it at 32768 chars. No warnings, no nothing.

Does anybody know a way to catch and disable it? Thanks.

Comment: How is the flat file adapter set up?

Comment: The flat file adapter reads the field into DT_TEXT. TruncationRowDisposition=RDFailComponent. 
What other properties are important here?